# c# Read and store XML nodes to string type reference

Tags: c#, xml

I have the below XML:
I need to read only the "ShortName" nodes, but to different string type reference.
How can I refer to source and get shortname's text and then do the same with target?
The xml contains more elements like Valid what I can read one by one with a code like this:

```
valid = TMElement.GetElementsByTagName("Valid")[0].InnerText;

<GlobalInfo>
 <LanguagePair>
  <Source>
    <ShortName>some data</ShortName>
  </Source>
  <Target>
    <ShortName>some data</ShortName>
  </Target>
</LanguagePair>
<Valid>true</Valid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string xml = @"<GlobalInfo>
                 <LanguagePair>
                   <Source>
                     <ShortName>some data source</ShortName>
                    </Source>
                    <Target>
                      <ShortName>some data target</ShortName>
                     </Target>
                 </LanguagePair>
                 <Valid>true</Valid>
               </GlobalInfo>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

LINQ query syntax:

```
string[] someDataSource = 
    (from data in xmlDoc.Descendants("Source")
     select data.Element("ShortName").Value).ToArray();

string[] someDataTarget = (from data in xmlDoc.Descendants("Target")
     select data.Element("ShortName").Value).ToArray();
```

or method syntax:

```
string[] someDataSource2 = xmlDoc.Descendants("Source").Select(x => x.Element("ShortName").Value).ToArray();
string[] someDataTarget2 = xmlDoc.Descendants("Target").Select(x => x.Element("ShortName").Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Import `using System.Xml;`

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        // if xml coming via string
        string myXml = "<GlobalInfo><LanguagePair><Source><ShortName>some data</ShortName></Source><Target><ShortName>some data</ShortName></Target></LanguagePair></GlobalInfo>";
        xdoc.LoadXml(myXml);

        string xpath = "GlobalInfo/LanguagePair";//specify path
        var nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody.
It seems this was easier than I though. Finally, I found my own solution.
Just for the records, I will post it here:

```
string source = TMElement.SelectSingleNode("LanguagePair/Source/ShortName").InnerText;
string target = TMElement.SelectSingleNode("LanguagePair/Target/ShortName").InnerText;
```